# Issue in coin change implementation (Java)

Tags: java, dynamic

I ran into an implementation problem when trying to solve this classic problem using DP. The problem is given a set of coins, and return the best way giving the least amount of coins.

```
import java.util.*;

class coin4
{
    static int coin_values[] = {16, 4, 8};
    static Map<Integer, Vector<Integer>> memo;
    static Vector<Integer> give(int n)
    {
        if(memo.containsKey(n))
            return memo.get(n);
        if(n<0)
            return null;
        if(n==0)
            return new Vector<Integer>();
        Vector<Integer> bestResult = null;
        for(Integer coin : coin_values)
        {
            Vector<Integer> result = give(n-coin);
            if(result != null)
            {
                result.add(coin);
                if(bestResult == null || bestResult.size() > result.size())
                    bestResult = result;
            }      
        }
        memo.put(n, bestResult);
        return bestResult;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int n=24;
        memo = new HashMap<>();
        Vector<Integer> result = give(n);
        if(result==null)
            System.out.println("No solution available");
        else
            for(Integer value: result)
                System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

It returns a vector containing [16, 4, 4, 8] while expecting [16, 8].
Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT 25/07: now it works perfectly!
wallet.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class InfiniteWallet {
    private Map<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> memo;
    private ArrayList<Integer> coinValues = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public void addCoin(int coin) {
        coinValues.add(coin);
    }

    public ArrayList<Integer> giveChange(int change) {
        memo = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>();
        Collections.sort(coinValues);
        Collections.reverse(coinValues);
        return give(change);
    }

    private ArrayList<Integer> give(int n) {
        if (memo.containsKey(n))
            if (memo.get(n) != null)
                return new ArrayList<Integer>(memo.get(n));
            else
                return null;
        if (n < 0)
            return null;
        if (n == 0)
            return new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> bestResult = null;
        for (Integer coin : coinValues) {
            ArrayList<Integer> result = give(n - coin);
            if (result != null) {
                result.add(coin);
                if (bestResult == null || bestResult.size() > result.size())
                    bestResult = result;
            }
        }
        memo.put(n, bestResult);
        if (bestResult != null)
            return new ArrayList<Integer>(bestResult);
        return null;
    }
    
    ArrayList<Integer> getCoinValues(){
        return new ArrayList<Integer>(coinValues);
    }
}
```

main.java

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InfiniteWallet wallet = new InfiniteWallet();
        wallet.addCoin(5);
        wallet.addCoin(395);
        wallet.addCoin(146);
        List<Integer> result = wallet.giveChange(768);
        if (result == null)
            System.out.println("No solution available");
        else
            for (Integer coin : wallet.getCoinValues())
                System.out.println(coin + " " + Collections.frequency(result, coin));
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: There are too many issues on the code. If you are trying to exercise recursive calls, I'd suggest you to first practice with factorial exercises, and study static and instance variables. If you insist on this code, add a `        System.out.println("n: "+n);` just inside the `give(n)` method to follow better the execution of your code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions  i was trying to rewrite in Java the code written in this video: https://youtu.be/oBt53YbR9Kk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you retrieve results from `memo`, you need to return a copy if you want to make changes to the cached vector. For example, when you do:

```java
result.add(coin)
```

if the vector `result` was retrieved from `memo` then you'll be adding `coin` to that original vector (and hence changing `memo` as well).

You can fix this by simply (one way to fix it, I should say) returning a copy of the vector in `memo` rather than the original. Simply replace:

```java
if(memo.containsKey(n))
    return memo.get(n);
```

with

```java
if(memo.containsKey(n))
    return new Vector(memo.get(n));
```

It's not the most performant way to fix it, but it's an easy fix.

Comment: Thanks you for your help! I usually work in c++, so most of the things are passed as copy in default! I wanted to rewrite the code in this video https://youtu.be/oBt53YbR9Kk